# how to horizontally align bootstrap flex items in different div flex containers

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to align flex items in ***different(!)*** div flex containers so the flex items have the same width like below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-flex alert p-0 mb-2">
  <div class="p-1 bg-primary" style="width: 130px">short</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-secondary" style="width: 110px">mediuuum</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-info" style="width: 80px">loooooong</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex alert p-0 mb-2">
  <div class="p-1 bg-primary" style="width: 130px">looooooooooong</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-secondary" style="width: 110px">short</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-info" style="width: 80px">mediuuum</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex alert p-0 mb-2">
  <div class="p-1 bg-primary" style="width: 130px">mediuuum</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-secondary" style="width: 110px">looooooooong</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-info" style="width: 80px">short</div>
</div>
```

notes:

- I have to render the flex divs (which are bootstrap alerts) in a loop, 1 by 1 (so only at the end it is clear what width to apply to horizontally align the columns)
- this is a simplified example. in reality the flex items contain different length...

this is how the flex items would be rendered withouth the custom width calculation:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-flex alert p-0 mb-2">
  <div class="p-1 bg-primary">short</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-secondary">mediuuum</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-info">loooooong</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex alert p-0 mb-2">
  <div class="p-1 bg-primary">looooooooooong</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-secondary">short</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-info">mediuuum</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex alert p-0 mb-2">
  <div class="p-1 bg-primary">mediuuum</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-secondary">looooooooong</div>
  <div class="p-1 bg-info">short</div>
</div>
```

maybe there is an "out of the box" functionality which is handling this in a less "width-hacky" way?

Comment: No there is not. CSS-Grid though... *does*

Comment: You can use css grid (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or bootstrap grid layout which is implemented using flexbox (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a table layout not a flexbox one:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-table">
<div class="d-table-row">
  <div class="d-table-cell p-1 bg-primary ">short</div>
  <div class="d-table-cell p-1 bg-secondary">mediuuum</div>
  <div class="d-table-cell p-1 bg-info">loooooong</div>
</div>
<div class="d-table-row">
  <div class="d-table-cell p-1 bg-primary">looooooooooong</div>
  <div class="d-table-cell p-1 bg-secondary">short</div>
  <div class="d-table-cell p-1 bg-info">mediuuum</div>
</div>
<div class="d-table-row">
  <div class="d-table-cell p-1 bg-primary">mediuuum</div>
  <div class="d-table-cell p-1 bg-secondary">looooooooong</div>
  <div class="d-table-cell p-1 bg-info">short</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. I thought about this but unfortunately it's not applicable in this case. the flex divs are alerts. I did not mention it in my question, I will add it now...

Comment: @udo I don't see why having them as *alert* make this not applicable

Comment: I am looking for a flexbox solution... it gives me a cleaner approach. I also have to remove the alerts (via "x" icon) which is more complicated as a table row. and gives a lot of overhead for what I am coding.